# read and write to different textures within same framebuffer

Tags: textures, framebuffer, texture2d, render-to-texture, webgl2

Is it possible to read from texture A and write to texture B that both use the same FBO? I don't believe this has been covered here already. Someone asked the question about [OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025827/read-from-one-texture-and-write-to-a-separate-texture-with-in-the-same-frame-buf), but not about WebGL. It seems like the answer is no, based on the answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014874/opengl-and-webgl-sampling-from-a-texture-attached-to-current-framebuffer), but if someone could tell me definitively whether reading/writing to textures in the same fbo is possible it'd really help me. In my code I get the following error:

WebGL warning: drawElementsInstanced: Texture level 0 would be read by TEXTURE_2D unit 0, but written by framebuffer attachment COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, which would be illegal feedback.

the following snippet generates an 'illegal feedback' warning. I know the code may not look/be useful but the point is accomplishing the read/write. To sumarize what I expect to happen is textureA (or call it texture 1) should be used to render to texture B ( aka texture 2 ). I should then see something on the screen; mostly likely 4 greed squares:

```js
/* YOU CAN PROBABLY IGNORE THIS AS IT'S INITIALIZATION CODE */

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
var fb;
var textures = [];

var tex_datei1 = new Array( 4*64*64 ).fill(9);

var vbo = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER , vbo );

var vertices = new Array( 4*64*64 ).fill( 0 );

gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER , vbo );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER , new Float32Array( vertices ) , gl.STATIC_DRAW );

var ibo = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER , ibo );

var indices = [ ...Array( vertices.length/4 ).keys() ];
indices[0] = 0;
indices[1] = 1;
indices[2] = 2;
indices[3] = 2;
indices[4] = 3;
indices[5] = 1;
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( indices ), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var vc = `#version 300 es
 precision mediump float;

 uniform sampler2D u_image0;
 uniform sampler2D u_image1;

 in vec3 coordinates;

void main(void) {

  float x = coordinates.x;
  float y = coordinates.y;

  vec4 sample_A = texture( u_image0 , vec2( x , y ) );
  sample_A.x *= 64.0 * 4.0;
  sample_A.y *= 64.0 * 4.0;

  gl_Position = vec4( sample_A.x/10.0 , sample_A.y/10.0 , 0.0 , 1.0 );

  gl_PointSize = 30.0;

}
`;

var vs = gl.createShader( gl.VERTEX_SHADER );
gl.shaderSource( vs , vc );
gl.compileShader(vs);
if( !gl.getShaderParameter( vs , gl.COMPILE_STATUS ) ){
  console.log( gl.COMPILE_STATUS );
  console.log( gl.getShaderInfoLog(vs) );
}

var fc = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
out vec4 color;
void main(void) {
  color = vec4( 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.0 , 1.0 );
}
`;

var fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fs, fc);
gl.compileShader(fs);
if( !gl.getShaderParameter( fs , gl.COMPILE_STATUS ) ){
  console.log( gl.COMPILE_STATUS );
  console.log( gl.getShaderInfoLog(fs) );
}

var program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vs);
gl.attachShader(program, fs);
gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.useProgram( program);

var coordinates_u_loc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "coordinates");
var u_image0_loc = gl.getUniformLocation( program , "u_image0");
var die_berechnung_u_image1Location = gl.getUniformLocation( program , "u_image1");

gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER , vbo );
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER , ibo );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( coordinates_u_loc );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( coordinates_u_loc , 4 , gl.FLOAT , false , 0 , 0 );
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
/* HERE IS WHERE I GET INTO FRAMEBUFFER SETUP */

fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer( gl.FRAMEBUFFER , fb );


gl.uniform1i( u_image0_loc , 0);
//gl.uniform1i( u_image1_loc , 1);


var internal_formats = [ gl.RGBA , gl.RGBA ];
var formats = [ gl.RGBA , gl.RGBA ];
var types = [ gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE , gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE ];

var datas = [ new Uint8Array( tex_datei1.slice() ) , new Uint8Array( tex_datei1.slice() ) ];

for( var i = 0 ; i < datas.length ; i++ ){

  var texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D , texture );

  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

  gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D ,
    0 ,
    internal_formats[i] ,
    64 ,
    64 ,
    0 ,
    formats[ i ] ,
    types[ i ] ,
    datas[ i ]
  );

  textures.push( texture );

 }

/* HERE MAY LIE MY ISSUE AS I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO SPECIFY THAT THE SECOND TEXTURE SHOULD BE WRITTEN TO. I'VE TRIED MESSING AROUND WITH THE LAYERS PARAMETER BUT THAT JUST CREATES MIPS ISSUES. */

gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D , textures[ 0 ] );
var attachmentPoint = gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0;
gl.framebufferTexture2D( gl.FRAMEBUFFER , attachmentPoint , gl.TEXTURE_2D , textures[ 0 ] , 0 );

gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D , textures[ 1 ] );
var attachmentPoint = gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1;
gl.framebufferTexture2D( gl.FRAMEBUFFER , attachmentPoint , gl.TEXTURE_2D , textures[ 1 ] , 0 );

var er = gl.checkFramebufferStatus( gl.FRAMEBUFFER );
if( er !== 36053 ){
  console.log( er );
}








 /* DRAW */

 gl.clearColor( 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 );
 gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
 gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

 gl.viewport( 0,0, 64 , 64 );

 gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textures[1] );

 gl.drawElements( gl.POINTS , indices.length , gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT , 0 );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <body>
      <canvas width="64" heigh="64" style="width:64px; height:64px; border:thick solid #0000FF; "></canvas>

    </body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to read from texture A and write to texture B that both use the same FBO

No, it is not possible. Why would you ever want to do that?

What are you trying to accomplish? Sometimes writing to A and sometimes writing to B? If so make 2 fbos. fboA and fboB, attach texture A to fboA and B to fboB. When you want to write to A bind fboA. When you want to write to B bind fboB. If you sometimes want to write to both make fboAB and attach both A and B.

As it is though the code is not setup to ever write to B when you have both textures attached. See: [WebGL 2.0: Multiple output textures from the same program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793336/webgl-2-0-multiple-output-textures-from-the-same-program)

## update

The code is attaching both `texture[0]` and `texture[1]` to a framebuffer. So at this point both `texture[0]` and `texture[1]` are setup for being written to. Also at that point `texture[1]` is bound to texture unit 0 for reading.

The shader only references one texture, even though it declares both `u_image0` and `u_image1` you never use `u_image1`.

The code then assigns `texture[1]` to texture unit 1 but it never sets `u_image0` so `u_image0` is using texture unit 0 since uniforms default to 0.

So then the code calls `gl.drawArrays`.  Because the framebuffer is using both `texture[0]` and `texture[1]` for writing and because the shader it using `texture[1]` on texture unit 0 for reading that's a feedback loop and so the code gets an error.

Here's a script you can paste at the top of the snippet HTML

```
<script src="https://greggman.github.io/webgl-helpers/webgl-check-framebuffer-feedback.js"></script>
```

from https://greggman.github.io/webgl-helpers/

When I do that and check the JavaScript console I see this error

> Uncaught Error: WebGL feedback loop: texture on uniform: u_image0 bound to texture unit 0 is also attached to current framebuffer on attachment: COLOR_ATTACHMENT1

If you want use texture A to generate texture B then at init time you attach B and only B to a framebuffer object

```
// at init time
const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                        gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureB, 0);
```

Then at render time you bind that framebuffer

```
// make gl.drawXXX write to textureB
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
```

Bind texture A to some texture unit.

```
const unit = 7;
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + unit);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE, textureA);
```

Tell the shader sampler what unit you put the texture on

```
gl.uniform1i(u_image0Location, unit);
```

More info [here](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html)

Comment: just to re-iterate I'm trying to read from A and write to B, not write to A and write to B.  The reason I want to do it is to take texture A and use some of its values to generate texture B.  Were you saying with your answer that reading A to write B isn't possible (illegal feedback)?

Comment: perfect. that's what I was missing...so i don't attach both to the frame buffer (as this is for writing, got it). i bind textures to texture units for reading. perfect. thanks again gman.